# Error Trying to do Left Outer Join BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do a relatively simple outer join but quite new to Big Query and I'm getting the following Error: internal error: missing closing bracket at: 2.3 - 2.39

```
SELECT
  ([130493328.ga_sessions_20170312].date),
  ([130493328.ga_sessions_20170312].total.visits),
  ([130493328.social].engagedUsers)
FROM ([130493328.ga_sessions_20170312]),
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [130493328.social]
ON
  ([130493328.ga_sessions_20170312].date) = ([130493328.social].date);
```

Could someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing this with table aliases:

```
SELECT ga.date, ga.total.visits, s.engagedUsers
FROM [130493328.ga_sessions_20170312] ga LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [130493328.social] s
     ON ga.date = s.date;
```

You should also check if you are using Legacy SQL or Standard SQL.  The square braces would not be appropriate in Standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it worked! Though not quite the result I was expecting, but still it worked.